# Exporting light and dark version of design

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am creating an icon with Illustrator, which I am trying to export in both a light and dark fill format.

Currently I have the icon with a dark version on an Artboard.
Is there anyway to export a light and dark version without having to export, then update fill, export, and undo fill change?

Not sure if this is possible with illustrator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do so:

1. Creat 2 separate artboards, export both (CMD+E);

[image]

2. Leave those two version of icons on the same artboards, drag the icons in to "Asset Export" panel, then export them.

[image]

Comment: This works nice but you should mention that it only applies to Illustrator CC. Here's a video tutorial on that matter: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/export-assets-web-app-design.html